# JTable reverts to old cells when clicked on

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

This Code is in a While Loop, and each time I run a new Query it will go through this block after I have chosen what to filter it by, the problem is when I run it a second time and click on a cell in my table it will revert to cells in my previous table/query. I attached an image to show what I mean(I need 10 reputation for that so nevermind on the picture), I filtered the table by procsessState = -1 and when I clicked on some cells it reverted to what the previous table had. Help would be greatly appreciated. The program is around 1000 lines long and I did a terrible job of splitting it into different classes So I just posted where I am almost certain the issue arises.

I declared

```
final String columnNamesForTable[] = {"Error Message", "ID", "Locked By", "Message Id", "Process State", 
            "Row Date", "Sender", "Sent Date", "Subject" };
```

At The top, then I have this a bit later on.

```
else if (checkBoxCounter != 0)
                {
                    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNamesForTable, 0);
                    tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
                    try 
                    {
                        Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
                        System.out.println("Connected");
                        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sb.toString(),
                                        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,
                                        ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
                        // Change CONCUR_READ_ONLY to CONCUR_UPDATABLE
                        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
                        int errorMessageIndex = resultSet.findColumn("ErrorMessage");
                        int idIndex = resultSet.findColumn("Id");
                        int lockedByIndex = resultSet.findColumn("LockedBy");
                        int messageIdIndex = resultSet.findColumn("MessageId");
                        int processStateIndex = resultSet.findColumn("ProcessState");
                        int rowDateIndex = resultSet.findColumn("RowDate");
                        int senderIndex = resultSet.findColumn("Sender");
                        int sentDateIndex = resultSet.findColumn("SentDate");
                        int subjectIndex = resultSet.findColumn("Subject");
                        while (resultSet.next()) {
                            Object[] rowsForTable = { resultSet.getString(errorMessageIndex), 
                                resultSet.getString(idIndex), resultSet.getString(lockedByIndex),
                                resultSet.getString(messageIdIndex), resultSet.getString(processStateIndex),
                                resultSet.getString(rowDateIndex), resultSet.getString(senderIndex),
                                resultSet.getString(sentDateIndex), resultSet.getString(subjectIndex)};
                            tableModel.addRow(rowsForTable);
                        }
                        resultSet.close();
                        statement.close();
                        conn.close();
                        filterFrame.setVisible(false);
                        JTable resultsTable = new JTable(tableModel);
                        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(resultsTable);
                        displayPnl.add(pane);
                        pack();
                        resultsTable.repaint();
                        isDone= true;
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database error");
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        isDone = true;
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error loading database driver");
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        isDone = true;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This Code is in a While Loop

Why would it be in a while loop. Swing is event driven. Code should only be executed when the uses generates some kind of event like clicking on a button, typing text, editing a cell.

> I have chosen what to filter it by,

Don't create a whole new table and scroll pane. Just update the TableModel of the existing JTable.

> pack();

Why would you pack the frame. The query could have 100's of rows of data. Pick a reasonable size for the table when the frame is created and there is no need to use pack() or repaint(). When you invoke the `setModel(...)` method of the JTable to replace the current model the table will be repainted automatically.

So all the code you need should be:

```
//filterFrame.setVisible(false);
//JTable resultsTable = new JTable(tableModel);
//JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(resultsTable);
//displayPnl.add(pane);
//pack();
//resultsTable.repaint();
existingTable.setModel( tableModel );
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it to work. The code is in awhile loop along with alot others so I can end certain parts in the actionListener. I tried making the table in the action listener due to having issues with it being final yesterday - I know its bad practice though

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment I do not have enough reputation.

1. You fire tabledatachanged before changing data.
2. TableDataChanged does not always properly update rows , it seems better to fire update rows.
3. If your table is editable , if you clicked the table you need to release the editor.

Comment: You should NOT invoke any fireXXX() method. That is the job of the TableModel.